# Hibernate mapping with multiple but separate Primary Keys (OR)

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I am currently working with hibernate and have already tried for a couple of weeks to find a solution for the following problem. As always a change of the tables is not possible.

There are two tables like this:

```
Table 1
     -> ID
     -> REF_ID
```

-

```
Table 2
     -> ID
```

ID is the primary key for each table. REF_ID is mostly 0, but sometimes contains valid IDs.

So I am looking to realize something like that in hibernate:

```
select        
    ....
from
    Table1 this_ 
inner join
    Table2 this_1_ 
        on this_.ID=this_1_.ID
        or this_.REF_ID=this_1_.ID
```

I have to apply certain criterias in the java code so I probably cannot use HQL. Also I am already using the code for other tables, so ideally I would like to use mapping files. My current mapping files look like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Table1" table="Table1">
        <id name="ID" type="string">
            <column name="ID" />
        </id>   
         <join table = "Table2"  fetch = "join">
            <key column ="ID"/>
        </join> 
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I hope someone can suggest a good approach.